# Android SharedPreferences com RadioButton

Tags: java, android-studio

Tenho dois RadioButton, quero selecionar um deles, fechar o app e quando abrir carregar a última seleção.

Podem me ajudar? Não encontro um tutorial claro explicado.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você sabe usar a *SharedPreferences*?

Answer (score 0):

O exemplo que vou dar é com `checkbox`, porem o método não é diferente, só altere para seu `radiobutton`.

Crie uma classe de preferencias. Nela você poderá armazenar tudo o que quiser.
Segue meu exemplo:

```
public class Preferencia {
    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("energy", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

  //// preferencia de checkbox
   public static boolean setcbremember(Context context, boolean a) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Cbremember", a);
        editor.commit();
        return a;

    }
    public static boolean getcbremember(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPref.getBoolean("Cbremember", true);
    }
 //// Deletar preferencia de login e senha
        public static void deletar(Context context, String login) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

    }

}
```

Onde eu salvo o `checkbox`, altere para o `radiobutton` e com um if e else, atribua ao `shared` o que o usuario escolher.

Segue o local onde eu recebo o `checkbox` para atribuir a preferencia:

```
public void btnentrarclick(View currentButton) {

        if(cbremember.isChecked()) {
            AcessoLogin ac = new AcessoLogin(Tela_de_Login.this,
                    edtlogin.getText().toString(), edtsenha.getText().toString());
            Preferencia.setlogin(Tela_de_Login.this, edtlogin.getText().toString());
            Preferencia.setsenha(Tela_de_Login.this, edtsenha.getText().toString());
            Preferencia.setcbremember(Tela_de_Login.this, cbremember.isChecked());

            ac.execute("");
        }
        else{

            AcessoLogin ac = new AcessoLogin(Tela_de_Login.this,
                    edtlogin.getText().toString(), edtsenha.getText().toString());
            Preferencia.deletar(Tela_de_Login.this, edtlogin.getText().toString());
            Preferencia.deletar(Tela_de_Login.this, edtsenha.getText().toString());

            ac.execute("");
        }

    }
```

No meu caso, como pode ver, se o usuario optar por `checkbox` acionado, ele salvará as informações do usuario, se ele desmarcar o checkbox, não salvará e apagará o que estiver salvo.
Espero que tenha ajudado

Comment: a resposta ficou boa, mas procure acentuar corretamente as palavras e frases, a resposta estava bem confusa sem acentuações devidas. Dessa forma, fica mais fácil entender corretamente. Não me entenda mal, é apenas uma dica pra que suas respostas sejam ainda melhores :)

Comment: muito obrigado..   vou verificar sim ...