# Como armazenar o valor de uma variável em java após do fim do programa?

Tags: java

Como armazenar o valor de uma variável em java após do fim do programa

Comment: Você pode armazena-la em um arquivo txt ou em um bd

Comment: Não tem algum tipo de variavel que faça isso para mim no java?

Comment: O programa vai ser encerrado certo?

Comment: Tem uma maneira um pouco mais dificil, aqui tem um tutorial. Veja se ajuda: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: se eu intendi direito a pergunta .. voce que armazenar algo mesmo com o programa fechado ..  tipo o login e senha de um usuario é isso???  se for  existe o sharedpreferences olha nesse link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128030/android-sharedpreferences-com-radiobutton/128109?noredirect=1#comment267161_128109

Comment: @Tiago,  ** sharedpreferences** seria para Android, certo?

Answer (score 1):

Para isto, você pode utilizar um [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) .

Neste caso, você deverá criar um arquivo para armazenar as informações que deseja salvar.

Segue um exemplo simples de como gravar e recuperar um objeto.

Este arquivo será salvo na raiz da aplicação.

Segue:

```
private static final File FILE= new File("MyObject.obj");


    /**
     * Salva um Serializable
     * @param object
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void save(MyObject object) throws IOException{
        final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE);
        final ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
        objectOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }

    /*
     * Carrega o Serializable 
     */
    public static MyObject load() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(FILE);
        final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        MyObject object = (MyObject)objectInputStream.readObject();
        objectInputStream.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
        return object;
    }




    /**
     * Objeto de exemplo, para que seja salvo é necessário implementar um Serializable
     */

    static class MyObject implements Serializable{
        /**
         * Serial é o identifica a versão da classe que será usada no processo de serializacão 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String value;
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```